# Add each item from one table into another table in Powerquery

Tags: powerquery

I have 2 queries with just one column. One with usernames, and another one with dates:

Table 1:

```
  | Username |
1 | User1    |
2 | User2    |
3 | User3    |
```

Table 2:

```
  | Date     |
1 | 1/1/2023 |
2 | 2/1/2023 |
3 | 2/1/2023 |
```

What I need to achieve is to add each user to each date. So the table I am trying to achieve is:

```
  | Date     | Username |
1 | 1/1/2023 | User1    |
2 | 1/1/2023 | User2    |
3 | 1/1/2023 | User3    |
4 | 2/1/2023 | User1    |
5 | 2/1/2023 | User2    |
6 | 2/1/2023 | User3    |
7 | 3/1/2023 | User1    |
8 | 3/1/2023 | User2    |
9 | 3/1/2023 | User3    |
```

How can I achieve this within power query?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Table2, add column, custom column with formula

= Table1

Then expand rows by using the arrow atop the new column

Comment: Wow. Was this really that easy? Thanks a lot @horseyride :)

Comment: Theres a complicated way if you want, where you add = 1 in a new column to each table, then merge and expand them :)

Comment: Lol, No thank you, I'm more than happy with the easy way :)